# Does "some good, some great" means there is nothing other(like "bad") than "good" or "great"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "some good, some great" means there **is nothing** other(like *some bad*) than *good* or *great*?

> [...] everybody has ideas, some good, some great. Good leaders listen to all [...]

There is no immediate reasons why to find out an answer to the above question, but when translated to my local language (and/or the verbal-space of it) (by me) yields that there **is something** other(like *some bad*) as well as *good* and *great*.

This is from a quote in a "values of a good leadership" on a back of a exercise book, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that some of the ideas you will have will be merely good, and others will be great. "good" and "great" are adjectives that qualify "ideas"

It doesn't strictly imply that none of your ideas will be bad, it's just not mentioning that possibility.

Comment: This is basically a rephrase of my quoted text: this is not an answer. I didn't ask you what is "good" or "great"? Are you got confused with "context" tag?

Comment: Have another look, fanboy.

Comment: your edit added a "correct" fact about the quoted text but again not an answer - being that your answer is OK or not; can you rephrase your second sentence? also, I am not a fanboy..

Comment: Has it occurred to you that your question may  not be phrased clearly enough?

Comment: Not. Your second sentence is I think is correct and answered but it has a lot of logic and jargon, lol. _Why does this need so many characters to post a comment_. tell me like how you would say it to kid, I am 24.

Comment: Some ideas will be good, some _very_ good. As Jack says, the sentence doesn't mention that there may be some bad ones as well.

Comment: Accepted by the explanation https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/300632/does-some-good-some-great-means-there-is-nothing-otherlike-bad-than-good/300638?noredirect=1#comment560678_300638